# Python keeping common code inside file

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I have some common code which are used in all my PyTest. I want to keep the complete code inside any file and load it during run time. Is it possible using Python ?

Eg:

```
def teardown_method(self, method):
 print "This is tear down method"
def setup_method(self, method):
 print "This is setup method"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from simply using `import`, for the example you showed (setup/teardown), you'd usually use a [pytest fixture](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) instead, and put them in a [`conftest.py`](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session) to share them between tests.

Comment: Yes I am using the contest.py for some common functions. In my case I need to update bTestStatus variable of my TestClass using the functions. How I can access those TestClass variable from conftest.py Eg:   class TestClass1:            bTestStatus = False                                                                              def teardown_method(self, method):
 print "This is tear down method"  TestClass1.bTestStatus = True
def setup_method(self, method):
 print "This is setup method"

Comment: also How I can move setup and Teardown method in contest.py